# ASP inline, adding time to a gridview column time type

Tags: asp.net, inline

How can I add or subtract time from an inline control field?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="eventTime"> 
  <EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eventTime") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
  </EditItemTemplate> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eventTime") %>'></asp:Label> 
  </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:TemplateField>
```

typically it would be something like this in VB.net....

```
Dim mytime As DateTime 
mytime = mytime.AddHours(7)
```

But I would like to do this inline.

Also is it possible to use a vairable from another parameter, something like

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eventTime") + Bind("timeOffset") %>'></asp:Label>to calculate the actual time to display on the fly?
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked....

```
<%# String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", Container.DataItem["eventTime"]) %>
```